# Stop DataSet coming to the Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, toolbox

In my C# windows application solution I've got a Reporting project which contains many datasets. Those datasets are loading to the toolbox automatically. I think that makes my visual studio  slower. Is there anyway to stop loading them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add

```
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
```

to the classes that you want to hide from the designer. more info from msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1k7z59.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designtimevisibleattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [TooboxAutoPopulate](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/07/23/speed-up-the-visual-studio-toolbox.aspx) setting....

Comment: I want this to apply only for the DataSets. ToolboxAutoPopulate doesn't help me in this case.